# Not able to define address space for CPU registers (Accumalator (A), index registers (XH and XL) in STM8S103F2 controller

Tags: assembly, stm8

In Assembly code, for STM8S103F2 controller, we can map the registers by the following syntax:

Example:
PA_ODR equ $5000
or
Segment byte at 5000 'cpu'
.PA_ODR         DS.B 1

but when it will come for CPU registers, both the syntax will not work.
A equ $7F00

or
Segment byte at 7F00 'cpu'
.A          DS.B 1

Can any one tell the reason why CPU register mapping will not work for STM8S103F2 controller.

Comment: `A equ $7F00` would redefine the symbol `A` as a number, so you couldn't use it as a register name anymore!  You probably don't want that.

Comment: `In Assembly code, for STM8S103F2 controller, we can map the registers by the following syntax:` Can you provide a reference for this so we can see what you are talking about? What assembler are you even using?